# How to openfiledialog using voice command

Tags: c#, forms

I want to open a `OpenFileDialog` using a voice command and I have an exception I couldn't view the File dialog I'm using a Form Application and Here's my code:

```
        private void StartVoiceCommand(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
       else if(e.Result.Text == "media")
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            speechSynthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female, VoiceAge.Teen);
            speechSynthesizer.Speak("Choose media files");
            speechSynthesizer.Dispose();
            openFilesToolStripMenuItem.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

and the `openfiletoolstripmenuitem` code is:

```
[STAThread]
private void openFilesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Media Files|*.mp3;*.mp4";
    open.Multiselect = true;
    if(DialogResult.OK == open.ShowDialog())
    {
        files = open.SafeFileNames;
        path = open.FileNames;
        for(int i =0;i<files.Length;i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my `Program.cs` code

```
    static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

and here's a picture for the exception
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are doing a cross thread  call which you need to eliminate. You will need to look at the Invoke method for forms application. If you search for InvokeRequired it should help. Edit: I could be wrong, if you post a more complete example of the failiing code I will take a look later on.

Comment: Try placing the `[STAThread]` attribute on the `Main()` entry point for your app.  Look at the very last C# example in this post for example code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I'm already read these before and I'm using it but nothing changed
` [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }`